# How to save animated GIF images drawing in Python turtle module?

Tags: python, gif, turtle-graphics

I am new to Python turtle module, I wrote a very easy code, like,

```
from turtle import *
import turtle
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(200)
circle(10)
ts = turtle.getscreen()
turtle.getcanvas().postscript(file = "duck.eps")
```

I got a `.eps` image, it looks well, but what I want is an animated image in `.gif`. However, when I try to say,

```
turtle.getcanvas().postscript(file = "duck.gif")
```

I got the duck.gif, but I cannot open it !!

What should I do now?

Comment: turtle use `tkinter` and `tkinter.Canvas` which can save only `postscript` files (`.ps`, `.eps`). `postscript` can't save animation.

Comment: you can only use external program to save all screen - ie. for Linux [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)

Comment: If you're using Mac OSX, I've just written up [how to create an animated GIF using just Python turtle and Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319971/is-there-a-way-to-save-turtles-drawing-as-a-gif/41353016#41353016)