# can't open this file python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to save my turtle created masterpiece to my computer, but when I try to open it, I get a message saying: can't open this file. this is my programming:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from math import *
from random import randint

    def k100():
            bob = Turtle()
            ts = bob.getscreen()
            name = input("what would you like to call your masterpiece? ")
            ts.getcanvas().postscript(file=(name, '.png'), colormode='color')

screen.onkey(k100, "o")
```

I have tried to save it as pdf, png, and a few others, but my pc says can't open this file every time - please help

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file=name+'.png'`?

Comment: You sure you r/w access to that file?

Comment: You're not actually changing the file-type that is being saved by changing the extension. You can make the extension whatever you want. Not sure what `tkinter` will return..

Comment: Yeah, see the comments to this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650099/how-to-save-animated-gif-images-drawing-in-python-turtle-module). It saves it as a postscript file. Which makes sense *given the method name*

Comment: I seem to be saving empty png's with this code without issues.... Although this being the postscript function I'm not sure it is meant to save png's. Have you tried running your program as admin?

Comment: @DirkHaupt what is running as admin?

Comment: @BretD what u mean? r/w???

Comment: @JRodDynamite it gives the same useless result

Comment: @Gurneyguy r/w means read and write access to the directory you are writing the file in.

Comment: @BretD what does that mean?

Comment: Right click whatever IDE you use (the program you program in) and click "run as administrator." This assumes you are on Windows and might give you r/w access for your code to work without error.

Comment: @DirkHaupt same result, thx for trying, any other recommendations?